# Limit voltage from rectifier

Tags: dc, current-limiting

So I bought a motorcycle voltage rectifier, but as I connected it to bike and tested it turned out that it produces about 15.08V at the peak, which is too much for battery and circuit boards. I wanted to know how i could still use this rectifier but limit the output voltage to let's say 14.20V at peak that could be good for acid battery.
So the question is: how to limit voltage if it exceeds 14.20V and don't limit if it is under 14.20V?

Comment: your average automotive battery won't mind an open-circuit voltage of 15 V. Also: measuring "true" voltage of something as non-perfect as a motorcycle alternator is a bit of a challenge. Your circuit boards, whatever they are, if used as part of motorcycle electronics, must have input protection and very likely a highly tolerant input-to-something-useful power supply integrated.

Comment: The battery should hold the system voltage down to 14 volts or so, depending on its state of charge.

Comment: is that 15.08 with no load? that will go down if so...

Comment: @dandavis yes thats with load. 15.08V hits at 5000 RPM with parking lights and low beam on.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My acid battery manual says voltage should not exceed 14.5V. Also I'v heard that battery could start to boil. Are you sure I can leave as it is?

Comment: have you actually tested with the battery connected? the load of a lead acid battery would very likely reduce the voltage you see sufficiently

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes it was with fitted battery. I actually replaced the old regulator/rectifier with new one, but as I tested that it let's through 15V I quickly replaced it back with the old one.

Comment: Was the orginal rectifier silicon and your new one schotky

Comment: @sstobbe sorry the documentation of new unit does not say that. Also it is glued, so i cant open it up. All i know is it has 3 white wires coming form generator and one red going out.

Comment: A 10A diode would drop the voltage about 0.7v on avg.

Comment: @MatissJurgelis You can measure the forward voltage of your new rectifier with the diode check of your multi-meter, schottky has a lower forward voltage  than silicon by ~0.4 V